# What does parametrize all such solutions implies

Tags: parametrization

When I am ask to parametrize all solutions can I just give the answer or do I have to proove that my parametrization is good?

Comment: You have to go $2$ ways to prove that your parametrization works. $(1)$ You have to make sure all solutions can be parametrized this way and $(2)$ you have to make sure all values obtained from the parametrization are solutions.

Comment: Further to @JoshuaWang's (2), it involves being specific about the set of allowed values for the parameters. For example, if you specify a circle in the plane of centre $(a,\,b)$ and radius $r$, $a,\,b\in\Bbb R$ and $r\in\Bbb R^+$.